# Graph Isomorphism of Complete Graph.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

what  Is the complexity(computational complexity) of  graph isomorphism of

1.Complete graphs($K_n$) and

2.Utility graphs (Complete bipartite graphs ,$K_{n,n}$)?

is it in  polynomial ?

Looks like trivial case, looking for  results. Thanks.

Edition :

1. "polarized graphs" isomorphism is a GI-complete problem (made of a complete graph $K_m$ and an empty graph $K_n$ plus some edges connecting the two; their isomorphism must preserve the partition)[Zemlyachenko, V. N.; Korneenko, N. M.; Tyshkevich, R. I. (1985), "Graph isomorphism problem", Journal of Mathematical Sciences 29 (4): 1426–1481 ].

Comment: What is the definition of "complexity of a graph isomorphism"?

Comment: @Moritz , time complexity of a graph isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\text{Aut}\left(K_n\right)\cong S_n$ and, if $m \neq n$, $\text{Aut}\left(K_{m,n}\right) \cong S_m\times S_n$, whereas $\text{Aut}\left(K_{n,n}\right)\cong C_2\times S_n^2$, where $C_k$ and $S_k$ are the cyclic group of order $k$ and the symmetric group on $k$ elements, respectively.  If your complexity is the size of the automorphism group, then the complexity is definitely not in polynomial.  If your complexity is the size of a minimal generating set of the automorphism group, then the complexity is constant.

Comment: in question $m=n$  , also what is the best  known bound, can u give link or paper containing results ?

Comment: What bound are you talking about?

Comment: I meant best time complexity

Comment: We still don't know what you mean by "time complexity."

Comment: planar graph isomorphism has  time complexity in log space(best result so far),  a class contained in P. analogous to this, what is the  best time complexity of complete graph ?

Comment: Are you talking about the graph isomorphism problem?  If so, then the time complexities for complete graphs and for symmetric complete bipartite graphs are both constant.  Two complete graphs are isomorphic iff they have the same number of vertices, and likewise for the symmetric complete bipartite graphs.  Even for all complete bipartite graphs, two are isomorphic iff they have the same bipartitions, whence also constant time complexity.

Answer (score -1):

Complete graphs, for isomorphism have constant complexity (time). In any way you can switch any 2 vertices, and you will get another isomorph graph. If you switch vertex A with B, conditions will be same for both, because both are connected with every other vertex. Daniel